# rails unable to pass instance variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4 for first time. Documentation says you can pass an instance variable to a partial:

```
<%= render partial: "customer", object: @new_customer %>
```

So I try to do the same. I am using fullcalendar engine and I render index.html.erb and inside that I render form partial. I pass @record to partial. I know the record is not nil because I added inspect_record helper to inspect that the @record does exist:

```
<%= render "form", :object => @record  %>
<%= inspect_record @record %>
```

However, in _form.html.erb partial, the @record is nil, and this condition returns false:

```
<% unless @record.nil? %>
```

Note I also tried this:

```
<%= render 'form', locals: {record: @record} %>
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: instance variables like `@this_one` defined in the controller's action should be available between the action's view and all partial views used.

Comment: Let us see the controller action where you populate `@record`

Comment: @JTG the issue was that the form was being rendered via an ajax call to a new action, not the index action.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using:

```
<%= render 'form', locals: {record: @record} %>
```

then, you will need to use variable `record` instead of `@record` in your `_form.html.erb` as:

```
<% unless record.nil? %>
```

**Description:**

`locals: {record: @record}` means, `@record`'s value will be accessible by using `record` in the partial being rendered.

Comment: Dan, if this one won't help, thought it should, try adding word partial, ```<%= render partial: 'form' .... ``` explicitly saying about partial.

Comment: @IvanShamatov good point, however, the partial is getting called successfully.

Comment: got this issue couple of times, when not adding 'partial' word affected on record, but it might be because of collection partial, or something like that, I cant remember actually.

Comment: @IvanShamatov  totally agree with you... I also have encountered this issue sometimes..

Comment: the issue was that the form was being rendered via an ajax call to a new action, not the index action. The new action does not have an existing @record with an id.